# rotate table and centralize it on page using abntex2

Tags: tables, rotating, sidewaystable, abntex2

On my work, I have a `table` that I need it to be rotated. I already did it, however it stays in the end of the page. Is there a better way to rotate and centralize it; or just centralize it?

I used  `\usepackage{rotating}` in the beginning of the document, and created the table using `sidewaystable`, like:

```
\begin{sidewaystable} [t]\scriptsize
\caption{ConvNet Configuration}\label{tab:1}
\begin{tabular}{*{6}{c}}
\hline
...
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}
```

The output is:

[image: Table generated by code]

**edit**: snippet of document is [here](http://dontpad.com/533175-overflow) since it's quite long

Comment: Welcome! Would you please complete the snippet to a short document from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`?

Comment: hey @egreg, thanks! I edited the question with it.

Comment: @mhery Posting the whole document with `\input` commands of files we don't have does not help anyone reproduce your problem. What egreg asked for was to make a compilable document containing *only* enough code to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using `{center}` tag on document:

```
\begin{sidewaystable}[t]\scriptsize
\caption{ConvNet Configuration}\label{tab:1}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{*{6}{l}}
\hline
...
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{sidewaystable}
```

Comment: The `center` environment might add some additional white space around the table. Better try with the `\centering` command instead.